Wien bridge oscillates at 6x expected freq and amplitude oscillates too
A while ago I made a Wien bridge oscillator to go from ~500 Hz to ~1 MHz, using an NE5532 opamp and stabilizing amplitude with the typical opposing diodes method. Worked fine, but the output was too wonky of a sinusoid for me, so I decided to rebuild it with better amplitude control. I'd read that some people have done that with a photoresistor in the gain network controlled by an LED whose brightness depends on output amplitude. I glued an LED face-to-face with a CdS photoresistor, put a couple layers of heatshrink over the top, and characterized the thing by varying LED current and measuring photoresistor resistance. Then, I made this schematic in LTspice:

VCC is 12V, and I didn't want to have to use a +- supply so there's a midpoint fake ground called "vgnd" to reference off. R2 (photoresistor) and R10 are the top half of the gain network, R1 is the bottom. R10 is there because with no LED current, the photoresistor is a number of megaohms. C1, C2, R3, and R4 form the other side of the Wien bridge. C1 & C2 are in reality a ganged-together variable capacitor unit, 30pF~640pF, and R3 & R4 are controlled together by a rotary switch.
R7, D1, R8, and C4 half-rectify and smooth the signal to measure amplitude, and Q1 buffers that to the LED. The negative leg of the LED is set by a voltage divider, so that nothing happens at all until the amplitude is sufficiently high.
I put RLED in for current sensing, because for whatever reason writing I(LED) directly causes the simulation to run so slowly you can barely perceive it moving. The magic formula at the bottom represents my characterization of the LED+photoresistor, and I've verified that different currents through the LED do set R2 to the expected values, so as janky as it looks, that part seems fine.
This is what I get in the simulation, for R3=R4=470k, C1=C2=640p, expected freq 530 Hz:

Fine, great, good, I like it. I can vary C1, C2, R3, R4 over the range 500 Hz~1 MHz, and at all frequencies I've tried, the amplitude oscillates slightly and settles down to a controlled level.
This does not happen in reality:

The amplitude control loop for whatever reason isn't adequately damped in real life. I can sort of fix that by introducing a 10k pot for RLED and varying it, which lets me get to a nice sine wave if I'm surpassingly surgical with my fingers. Even barely beyond the right position, the amplitude goes into oscillation. I've tried adjusting R7, R8, and C4 upwards and downwards, which only changes the frequency of amplitude oscillation, not how sensitive the system is to me adjusting RLED and not how stable the amplitude is.
Alright, very annoying though maybe I can live with that, but what I can't live with is the fact that instead of the expected and simulation-agreed 530 Hz, I see about 3.1 KHz.
My first thought was some stray capacitance/whatever skewing the frequency (probably unlikely given it's on perfboard), but the factor by which the frequency is wrong (5.9) is constant over the whole sweep of the variable cap (up to 70 kHz). Changing R3 and R4 for other values also doesn't change it. I don't understand what could cause the frequency to be scaled so uniformly. Some significant phase shift introduced somewhere?

What happens if you shunt C3 with a 100uF electrolytic?

@SpehroPefhany The output distorts a little while the 100uF charges up, but once it has, no change

Is your simulation using actual component models... or ideal components?
Measure the phase shift of the signal as it propagates through your circuit... input to output.... back to input.

Hmm. Okay. I was wondering if you're using ceramic caps so C3/C4 may be much less than expected capacitance. If you remove the feedback entirely by opening R7 or D1 do you still get an unexpected frequency?

CdS elements are only linear for small signals - say 10mV order-of-magnitude. Check in the simulation the amplitude of voltage across R2. If it's higher than 10mV, then you'll have to modify the circuit to fix that. It almost seems like in your circuit the CdS generates a strong harmonic that the oscillator locks onto. CdS have excellent THD for small signals, but small signals only.

@user324996 that debugging tip solved half the problem I think! The node between C2 and R4 lags about 30 deg compared to the amp output & inputs, which is only possible if the capacitor is nearer 100 pF, despite what it says on it and how my previous circuit behaved... oh well. Thanks!

Add power supply decoupling capacitors across the op amp pins. Also to the fake ground node.
